# getting schema + first 100 records from every table in a db

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a large sql server db, and i want to get the schema (all tables/triggers/sprocs), i'm pretty sure that's easy.

but the tough part is that i want to get 100 records from each table.  it's a huge db on a remote server and i can't develop locally without a mockup copy.

thanks for your help!

Comment: 100 of each table might be messy if you've got lots of lookups and the 100s don't match up with each other.

Comment: And the larger the tables get, the less likely your foreign keys are to match up.

Comment: yeah, that's right it will be messy and it might not match up, but that's ok, i can deal with that.  i just would really like a quick way to do this but i still can't find one without writing a bunch of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the schema, basically just select everything from the `sys.objects` catalog view:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
```

For the data: you could use the undocumented (but extremely helpful) stored procedure [sp_MSForEachTable](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm) for that purpose:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'select top 100 * from ? '
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a cursor with sys.objects to get the user defined tables and populate the new database with select query of top 100 rows.

Make sure you have (NOLOCK) hint to your query, so that it can avoid locks